# TFS Allow all states for a work item

Tags: tfs-workitem

Is it possible to open up all possible states for a work item - essentially removing the state transitions?

I am hoping to use a tool outside of TFS for managing work items and would like to know if it's possible to simply allow all states at any time?

Comment: I am still searching for a solution. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the transitions between work item, you need to customize the work flow.

> You change the workflow to accomplish the following objectives:
>
> **Add or remove a state, reason, or transition**.
>
> Specify a value for field to be applied during a change in state,
>   reason, or transition..
>
> Specify a custom ACTION to automate field assignments based on a
>   change in state, reason, or transition.

Detail steps to customize the workflow and more info about it, please refer this [Modify or add a custom work item type (WIT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409273.aspx) from MSDN.

Moreover, here is a 3rd party extension called **[TFS Work Item Manager](http://www.telerik.com/teampulse/tfs)**  which is an innovative team workload coordination platform that helps you manage your TFS work items in a much more efficient and intuitive way. You can also take a look at it.

Comment: So does that mean that if I want any status to be able to transition to any status that I would have map out all possibilities?  Surely, there is a better way.